# mySQL query to return minimum state duration for a given period

Tags: mysql, sql, duration

I have the following data in a MySQL database table, and I'd like to calculate the minimum duration `where state = 1` for a given period, to place into a Grafana stat.

Within this table snippet, the desired result would be the `timestampdiff()` between row 10 and 8, i.e. 2 minutes.

| id | loc | temp | state | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | room_1 | 19.4 | 0 | 2022-12-29 18:14:09 |
| 2 | room_1 | 19.3 | 0 | 2022-12-29 18:15:09 |
| 3 | room_1 | 19.2 | 1 | 2022-12-29 18:16:09 |
| 4 | room_1 | 19.2 | 1 | 2022-12-29 18:17:09 |
| 5 | room_1 | 19.2 | 1 | 2022-12-29 18:18:09 |
| 6 | room_1 | 19.2 | 0 | 2022-12-29 18:19:10 |
| 7 | room_1 | 19.2 | 0 | 2022-12-29 18:20:10 |
| 8 | room_1 | 19.1 | 1 | 2022-12-29 18:21:10 |
| 9 | room_1 | 19.0 | 1 | 2022-12-29 18:22:10 |
| 10 | room_1 | 19.0 | 0 | 2022-12-29 18:23:10 |

I've tried numerous faulty solutions from chatGPT that I won't post here for obvious reasons.

The period part is simple enough using the Grafana global variable `WHERE $__timeFilter(datetime)` and using that I can calculate the *total* duration `WHERE state = 1 AND $__timeFilter(datetime)` because the record generation is on a 1-minute basis which makes summing the binary 0/1 state column an easy out (obviously doesn't require the `state = 1`).

I'm completely lost trying to work with duration periods within a period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query requirements that you had was bit complex, I had to use windows function - LAG to get the results. Below is the query that you need.

```
WITH temp_prev_state AS (
SELECT id, loc, temp, state, datetime_, LAG(state,1)  OVER(  ORDER BY datetime_  ) AS prev_state FROM Temperature
), latest_on_off_stateSession AS (
(SELECT * from temp_prev_state where state = '0' and prev_state = '1' ORDER BY datetime_ DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
UNION
(SELECT * from temp_prev_state where state = '1' and prev_state = '0' ORDER BY datetime_ DESC LIMIT 1 )
), lat_on_off_prev_dt AS (
SELECT *, LAG(datetime_,1)  OVER(  ORDER BY datetime_  ) AS prev_datetime_ FROM latest_on_off_stateSession
)
select id, loc, temp, state, datetime_, ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,datetime_ ,prev_datetime_)) AS abs_Time_Diff_Mins FROM lat_on_off_prev_dt
```

**The output of the query:**
[image]

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sm7q9P7Y)

Comment: This has exposed an issue I was unaware of when I built this little database. The installed version (5.7)  does not have window functions - ```LAG()``` and ```OVER()``` throw errors. Perhaps time to move to MariaDB. Appreciate the very thorough answer.